# Windows 8 - Running .bat files from folder - Scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, task

I'm in a bit of a pickle here.
I created a .bat file that works great in Windows 7, here it is:

```
@echo off
cd ./Tasks
set CurrentDir=%cd%
schtasks /create /xml "%CurrentDir%/Scheduled Restart, Shutdown.xml" /tn "Callcenter     Tasks\Scheduled restart"
schtasks /create /xml "%CurrentDir%/Scheduled Restart, Shutdown (part 2).xml" /tn     "Callcenter Tasks\Scheduled restart part 2"
exit /b 0
```

The .bat file is on a network drive.
As you can see it will change the dir to ./Tasks inside the folder from which it was executed.
Next of it will set a parameter that %CurrentDir% is it's current dir. :-)
So now I can run a path like this:
`"%CurrentDir%/Scheduled Restart, Shutdown (part 2).xml"`
*instead of*
`Z:/Tasks/Tasks/Scheduled Restart, Shutdown (part 2).xml`
(A full path)
Which can help a lot in certain circumstances.

Like i said, the script works great in Windows 7, but when running it from Windows 8 it gives me an error since the path is incorrect.
Somehow, windows 8 keeps the path from C:/Windows/System32 instead of the path from which the .bat was executed.

How to solve this, any suggestions, ideas?

**Help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Is the batch file running as administrator?  Does the batch file work without the scheduled task?

Comment: Yes and Yes.
The bat file runs perfectly on Windows 7, but not on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might be having a problem with the `Linkedconnections` feature on win8

Try setting this regkey and see if it works:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

[Source](http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/)